# Inject a dao into Worker with Hilt problem

Tags: android, dependency-injection, android-workmanager, dagger-hilt

I have initiated a worker in my App class like below;

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class KutuphanemApplication:Application(),Configuration.Provider {

@Inject
lateinit var workerFactory: HiltWorkerFactory

override fun getWorkManagerConfiguration() =
    Configuration.Builder()
        .setMinimumLoggingLevel(android.util.Log.DEBUG)
        .setWorkerFactory(workerFactory)
        .build()
```

I want to inject a singleton dao into my worker class for update something in DB. So I am injecting dao like below;

```
 @HiltWorker
 class ClearImageNotInArchiveWorker @AssistedInject constructor(
      @Assisted val appContext: Context,
      @Assisted val workerParams: WorkerParameters,
      private val kitapDao: KitapDao): CoroutineWorker(appContext, workerParams) {

override suspend fun doWork(): Result {...}
}
```

When I enquee this WorkManager class in App class , I am getting

**WorkerFactory: Could not instantiate com.mesutemre.kutuphanem.job.ClearImageNotInArchiveWorker**
error. But application is not crashing. Is there any problem about injecting dao in here?

Also my singleton dao;

```
@Singleton
@Provides
fun provideKitapDao(database: KutuphanemDatabase) = database.getKitapDao();
```

Comment: Did you [disable the default WorkManager initializer](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/custom-configuration)?

Comment: I removed it from manifest

Answer (score 9):

I solved the problem. I messed up hilt-compiler kapts. I have added

```
  kapt("androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0")
```

into the gradle then I added

```
<provider
   android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
   android:authorities="${applicationId}.androidx-startup"
   tools:node="remove">
</provider>
```

into AndroidManifest.xml . Then the problem solved.

Comment: wow! you save me!